# Jquery Position absolute validator plugin wont work online

Tags: html, jquery-plugins

I am using this plugin

http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

It works perfect in dreamweaver offline as soon as I upload it to my web server hosted by one.com it doesn't work. It uses the jquery validation engine and css to display error messages.

When online the form displays but wont validate.

This is the webpage I cant get it to work on

http://www.notgotaclue.co.uk/contactUs.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

These are the js files currently loaded by your application
[image: These are the js files currently loaded by your application]

---

You need to include all these missing jquery and js files

[image: You need to include all the jquery and js files]

---

and also add correct file path references

[image: and also add correct file path references]

Comment: Thank You \m/ I hate how everything is so case sensitive. Won't forget that again in a hurry :p